# fatal: Could not read from remote repository npm install

Tags: javascript

When I am running npm install in Mac:

```
sudo npm install --save umi/dynamic umi/link umi/navlink umi/redirect umi/router umi/withRouter
```

throws this error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/umi/router.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dolphin/.npm/_logs/2019-09-10T01_52_01_900Z-debug.log
```

why npm install ssh access github failed? what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: is your repository private? if private them have to create to SSH connection or some Credentials based connection !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you list a git repository as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

```
"somepackage": "git://github.com/someorg/somerepo.git"
```

If the repository is `public`, *swap* the URL to an HTTP URL:

```
"somepackage": "https://github.com/someorg/somerepo"
```

If the repository is private, enable user keys in Project settings > Checkout SSH keys. See [this document](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#enable-your-project-to-check-out-additional-private-repositories) for more information .

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it just says "fatal: Could not read from remote repository." and still tries to use SSH for some reason, despite explicitly using https

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to delete `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` for it to work as these cache the URL to resolve the packages.

Answer (score 0):

What I personally did was clear everything doing:

```
rm -rf node_modules

rm -rf package-lock.json

npm cache clean --force

php artisan cache:clear (create data folder if fails)

php artisan key:generate

php artisan config:clear

php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

composer update

git pull origin BRANCHNAME

npm install
```

seemed to work after all that. Might be able to achieve the same results just from running `git pull origin BRANCHNAME`, before doing npm install, but did those other commands beforehand so I don't 100% know if the other commands helped or not